# Storing a JSON file in Redis and retrieving it

Tags: json, node.js, redis

I am storing the info contained in a JSON file in Redis. I am doing it with the nodejs redis driver. Do you think that I am losing something if I am employing a hashtable for storing the info? 
The info is simply a large array (several thousands) of elements (several fields within every element, no more than 50 fields sometimes) in the data and a small bunch of properties in the meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you're storing those JSON strings as follows:

```
hset some-key some-sub-key <the json>
```

Actually there's another valid approach which involves using the global key space directly:

```
set some-key:sub-key <the json>
```

If you're just storing those JSON strings I would say that creating global space keys is the simplest and most effective approach in your case.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by losing something? Storing values(JSON) and retrieving them in Redis could be really fast. Plus Redis comes with some very handy APIs like TTL, FLUSHALL etc...

Personally, I'm using Redis for my Profile page. I store my image uploads in Redis and never had an issue.

My profile page: http://fanjin.computer

Github repo: https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery

Comment: OK, for instance, somebody wrote that storing with the hash can be slow, and I employed rebridge but I also have read that can be dangerous, so I have change to employ directly the redis client. So far so good, because is really fast during the tests (I am having problems with the format but I think i can fix it)  I just prefer not to develop too much without commenting with other people.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been answered, for future reference some might be asking the same question but looking for a different answer (like me).

If that's the case I would suggest looking in to [RedisJSON](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/) for creating a JSON type in redis.